# Counting sum every 7th while loop

Tags: javascript, function, while-loop, sum

I'm having a hard time with this problem here:

> Write a function named sumEvery7th that accepts a
>   non negative integer `n` and returns the sum integers divisible by 7.
>   Use a `while` loop

I have this code so far but `console.log(sumEvery7th(25));` outputs 63 when it should output 42

```
function sumEvery7th(n){
  let sum=0;
  var i=7;
  while (i<=n) {
    i+=7
    sum+=i;
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumEvery7th(25)); // 7+14+21=42
console.log(sumEvery7th(0)); // expect 0
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Increment `i`, after you have added the `sum`

Comment: Since you are initializing `i` at 7, you need to swap the order of `i+=7` and `sum+=i`. Right now you are starting your sum at 14 rather than 7.

Comment: When running the func with 25 you are adding up 14+21+28. You are ignoring the first 7 because you increment i and then add it to the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is out of order inside the `for` loop. There are two ways you can address this:

You need to increase the sum and then increment the iterated value. Just simply switch the line for incrementing `i` by 7 to be below the sum addition and you're good to go.

```js
function sumEvery7th(n){
  let sum=0;
  var i=7;
  while (i<=n) {
    sum+=i;
    i+=7;
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumEvery7th(25)); // 7+14+21=42
console.log(sumEvery7th(0)); // expect 0
```

Or you could set `i` to 0 and get the same result

```js
function sumEvery7th(n){
  let sum=0;
  var i=0;
  while (i<=n) {
    i+=7
    sum+=i;
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumEvery7th(25)); // 7+14+21=42
console.log(sumEvery7th(0)); // expect 0
```

choose whichever feels more natural to you as both are correct logic.

Remember: *order of operations is important*

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a `for` loop:

```js
const sumEvery7th = (n) => {
    let sum = 0;

    for (let i = 7; i <= n; i += 7) {
 sum += i;
    }

    return sum;
}

console.log("50 -> ", sumEvery7th(50));
console.log("25 -> ", sumEvery7th(25));
console.log("7 -> ", sumEvery7th(7));
console.log("6 -> ", sumEvery7th(6));
console.log("0 -> ", sumEvery7th(0));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the order of lines in `while` loop

```js
function sumEvery7th(n) {
  let sum = 0;
  var i = 7;
  while (i < n) {
    sum += i;
    i += 7

  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumEvery7th(25)); // 42
console.log(sumEvery7th(0)); // 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The line sum+=i; should come before i+=7

Answer (score 0):

The input is also the increment number. `int--`
Exit loop when the there is no more input left. `while (int > 0) {...`
Check by modulus on every iteration. `if (int % 7 === 0) {...`
When a factor of 7 is found add it to `sum`. `sum +=int`

Made it a little more useful by adding a second parameter for the factor. Now you can use something other than 7.

```js
function sumOfFactors(int, fac) {
  let sum = 0;
  while (int > 0) {
    int--;
    if (int % fac === 0) {
      sum += int;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumOfFactors(25, 7));
console.log(sumOfFactors(58, 7));
console.log(sumOfFactors(0, 7));
console.log(sumOfFactors(77, 7));
```